# Copying images and data_files in py2exe not working?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, py2exe

I am trying to convert a python Tkinter application into a .exe executable file with py2exe. My python Tkinter program has many images in it. When I created my setup file for py2exe, I created a data_files directory for the images to copy too, but it does not seem to work. I have verified all of the directories for my pictures in my setup file and they are all correct. I don't know why my icons and .gif files are not being copied. Please help.

Here is my error:

[image: My Error]

Comment: How did you define the filename? Looks like you used `\t` or other such escape sequences somewhere.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I defined my filename like this: "C:\Users\RohRoh\Desktop\tusc\tsicon.ico" in my setup.py file

Comment: @MartijnPieters I did not use \t also

Comment: use `r"C:\Users\RohRoh\Desktop\tusc\tsicon.ico"` raw string

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to double the backslashes in your path:

```
'C:\\Users\\RohRoh\\Desktop\\tusc\\tsicon.ico'
```

or use a raw string literal:

```
r'C:\Users\RohRoh\Desktop\tusc\tsicon.ico'
```

or *forward* slashes:

```
'C:/Users/RohRoh/Desktop/tusc/tsicon.ico'
```

In a Python string, `\t` is *one* tab character, not two separate characters.

Comment: I have tried all of these and I even changed the icon name and now I keep on getting the same error saying that the icon, now renamed, "standardicon.ico" is not defined. How do I fix this?